# How retain focus on the same field, where user was, after page refresh in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The question seems to be basic but I would ask.

Is there a standard way to retain focus on the same field (where user was, before refresh) after page refresh in MVC3.

for simplicity purpose, I will take a simple scenario. scenario is like

I have three controls on a page.

1. a textbox ---Name
2. a dropdown ---Country)
3. another dropdown---City (which loads cities from server based on the country selected in field 2 and this causes the page to refresh)

What I want,

the focus to be on Country field, after page refresh.

I hope, the question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want, just use jQuery's .focus function (http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

You may want to consider loading your dropdown dynamically through jQuery or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) so that you don't get the page refresh.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but, I think, there need to be something simpler solution, because in this case, if there are multiple controls on a page, which causes refresh. then I have to remember which control causes, the refresh, then I will be able write that jquery focus script.

Comment: in that case use ajax, and fill your drop down list dynamically using jquery, and there won't be any page refresh at all.